# How to say "Don't stroke his ego"?

Tags: idioms, english-to-japanese

Is there an equivalent of "Don't stroke his ego" in Japanese? I assume that such a phrase would be relevant in Japanese, but I've never heard it.

Thanks!

Comment: 「あんまり褒めると調子に乗るからやめとけ」とかでどうかな？ちょっと違う？

Comment: It kind of makes sense. "A surplus of praise causes cockiness so stop". The meaning is similar.

Answer (score 3):

There should be a dozen or more "equivalents".　As a general tip, you will always receive a better answer if you let us know who is speaking to who -- ages, genders, relationship, etc.　The more information you give, the better and more natural the phrases will be.

Off the top of my head, I could give you:

「おだてるのはやめた[方]{ほう}がいい。」

「おだてない方がいい。」

「[自尊心]{じそんしん}をくすぐるような[事]{こと}をするな/事はしない方がいい。」

「[機嫌]{きげん}を[取]{と}ることないって！」

Comment: I think「おだてない方がいい」is crisp and closest to the idiom, "stroke sb's ego. Though it might be the gild to lily, you can add '余り'ーtoo much - like あまり彼を煽てない方がいい to 'soften' the  tone of your message.